# Why we need Discovery URL in OpenID

Tags: openid

Like  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id and https://me.yahoo.com they send me the end point (https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud for google and https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth for yahoo)
So my question is can I skip this I just use the endpoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the [initiation and discovery](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery) phase of the OpenID protocol, a user may pass either a URI or an [XRI](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/15376). If a URI is given then the [YADIS protocol](http://yadis.org/papers/yadis-v1.0.pdf) must be followed to find the service endpoint.

If the URL given is different to the endpoint then the URL becomes the 'claimed identifier' and the OpenID provider can also provide an 'OP local identifier'. A user does not need to specify an endpoint url when initiating the protocol. Therefore this step should not be skipped.

As part of the discovery phase, various OpenID extensions may also be discovered which may be helpful to your application.

[The OpenID protocol is documented pretty well.](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery)

However, there is no reason why you can't cache the results of the discovery. Whilst you could write code to skip the discovery phase if the Yahoo! or Google endpoint URL is given, a cache is a more generalised solution that will not break if the extensions available are altered.